# Symmetric relationship in EF Code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, poco, self-reference

I'm not sure if I've got my wording correct (which might be why I'm struggling to find results).

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I'd like to be able to be able to add a collection of related products (Product B, Product C) to Product A. I'd like it so that when you then look at Product B, the related products reflect what's been added on A (as in you would see Product A and Product C).
Does there have to be a separate table just for the 'related' relationships? I'm guessing there's a simple way to do this.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string DefinitionUri { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> RelatedProducts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just a grouping of products in something like a `ProductGroup`? (So, a separate entity)

Comment: I'm not really trying to create a ProductGroup for Products to be placed in. I want both admins and an algorithm to be able to relate products (symmetrically) and be able to access them simply (as in, I can just access the RelatedProducts property) and efficiently (not needing to 'find' related products based on other properties every time the property is accessed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you are trying to do is similar to what you see on amazon.com for instance, if you opened a book it will give you related books to check out. if i am guessing correctly then this is a many-to-many relationship you are trying to configure since every product might be related to many other products, now Entity Framework Code First supports many-to-many relationships by conventions and creates a join table automatically. now i haven't tried where both related objects are of the same type (in your case "Product") so you will have to check to see if this works out. On a side note, i don't think this is the way this feature should be implemented, i think you have to use some sort of Data Mining techniques, i would Google for that and see how professionals implement this functionality.

Comment: Creating a join table and having an asymmetric 'Related Products' relationship is easy enough, but I'd like it so that it's symmetric (my second paragraph rambles about this). I shall look into the datamining techniques - but that sounds a little terrifying for what would be a relatively small feature on what I'm working on. Thanks though!

Comment: @NickDarvey were you able to find an answer for your needs? I have the same question and couldn't find it yet. Solution provided by Gert Arnold above is exactly the "asymmetric" case, right?

Comment: @tyron I haven't looked at this again so no I didn't find a solution and I am now a bit far away from Entity Framework, sorry.

Comment: @tyron - Sorry for the late reply. I think I dropped that idea. What Sniffer said would probably be what I'd do if I had to implement it right now. It's probably not the most efficient but you could do it through a many-to-many relationship (Products has many Products). You could use EF conventions or manually create a join table that relates one Product ID to another Product ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property as you defined it, but you should tell EF that it is a many to many association, e.g. like so:

```
entry.HasMany(p => p.RelatedProducts)
     .WithMany()
     .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("ProductId")
                .MapRightKey("ProductIdReleated"));
```

Now Ef will create a junction table with two FKs to `Product`. Without this mapping it will create a `Product` table with an FK to itself, i.e. a `1-n` association.